# How to compare html time to current time and change color

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a table with different times in a td tag.
I want to compare the times in the tds to the current time and depending on that I want to change the color via javascript:

Could you please tell me what I have to put in my if argument/comparison in the bottom of my code?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>FlightNr</th>
                        <th>from</th>
                        <th>scheduled</th>
                        <th>Gate</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>KP7809</td>
                        <td>Queilén</td>
                        <td class="time">06:30</td>
                        <td>M13</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>BR2168</td>
                        <td>Gargazzone/Gargazon</td>
                        <td class="time">07:45</td>
                        <td>N12</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>GN5746</td>
                        <td>Surat</td>
                        <td class="time">08:50</td>
                        <td>X58</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var now = new Date();
    var h = now.getHours();
    var m = now.getMinutes();
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("time");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if(time in td tags are older than current time)
        x[i].style.color ="red";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should have to try any way to deal with date object of the JavaScript first! Also you did not specify the comparison. As a **hint** you will have to transform current time and times collected from the table into a timestamp integer.

Comment: Does my response answers your question? If yes then can you accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the value from string to an int. After this, you can compare it with the current time. Thus, your loop would look like:

```
var hoursInTd = parseInt(x[i].innerText.split(':')[0]) 
var minutesInTd = parseInt(x[i].innerText.split(':')[1])

if (hoursInTd > h) {
   // hours in td are later
   x[i].style.color ="red";
} else if (hoursInTd === h && minutesInTd > m) {
   // hours are same, but the minutes are later
   x[i].style.color ="red";
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have used timestamps to compare the current date and your desired date.
Note that I'am assuming that the dates on the table are on the same day of today. Cheers.

```js
var now = new Date();   
var timeContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("time");

for (var i = 0; i < timeContainers.length; i++) {
   var [hours,minutes] = timeContainers[i].innerHTML.split(':');
   var dateToCompare = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),Number(hours),Number(minutes))
    if(now.valueOf() - dateToCompare.valueOf() > 0){
      timeContainers[i].style.color='red';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>FlightNr</th>
                        <th>from</th>
                        <th>scheduled</th>
                        <th>Gate</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>KP7809</td>
                        <td>Queilén</td>
                        <td class="time">06:30</td>
                        <td>M13</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>BR2168</td>
                        <td>Gargazzone/Gargazon</td>
                        <td class="time">07:45</td>
                        <td>N12</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>GN5746</td>
                        <td>Surat</td>
                        <td class="time">08:50</td>
                        <td>X58</td>
                    </tr>
                    
                     <tr>
                        <td>GN5746</td>
                        <td>Surat</td>
                        <td class="time">18:50</td>
                        <td>X58</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the time in to a date object and compare it with the current date.

```js
var now = new Date();
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("time");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var time = new Date(Date.parse('01/01/2011'+ ' ' + x[i].innerHTML))
        if(time < now){
        console.log(x[i].innerHTML)
            x[i].style.color = "red";
        }
        
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>FlightNr</th>
                        <th>from</th>
                        <th>scheduled</th>
                        <th>Gate</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>KP7809</td>
                        <td>Queilén</td>
                        <td class="time">06:30</td>
                        <td>M13</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>BR2168</td>
                        <td>Gargazzone/Gargazon</td>
                        <td class="time">07:45</td>
                        <td>N12</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>GN5746</td>
                        <td>Surat</td>
                        <td class="time">08:50</td>
                        <td>X58</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```